# two indices in one table, is second index which is used only in where clause worth it?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Lets say, I have the following mysql table :

```
CREATE TABLE player (
    id int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
    score MEDIUMINT(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    signupdate DATE NOT NULL,
    lastupdate DATE NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Currently I have a primary key on id column. lastupdate column is updated everyday, and if its not updated it means that the player has deleted the account, this means the cardianlity of this column is very low. 
Also there is a relational table matches with feilds `matchid` , `playerid` and `matchdate`

Most my queries are like

```
SELECT id,score,signupdate FROM player 
JOIN matches ON matches.playerid = player.id 
WHERE lastupdate = '{today}'
```

So 3 cases for indices come to my mind

1. PRIMARY KEY on id
2. PRIMARY KEY on id and an INDEX on lastupdate
3. PRIMARY KEY on (id,lastupdate)

Which one would be the best??

Comment: by definition, a primary key defines the unicity of a row. ID by itself should be the primary key because it is unique by itself. Then, mysql will *probably* be able to compute merge optimisations on your indices if you add one on `lastupdate`.

Comment: Number 3 would mean that you can have many users with the same id: one for every lastupdate. So number 3 is not a bad solution, but is no solution at all because it changes the behaviour of the database. With a primary key (id) you will have a unique id, with (id, last_updated) you will have no unique ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an index on table `matches` column `playerid` and an index on table `player` column `lastupdate`.

As a very rough rule of thumb is that what you use in the `WHERE` and `JOIN` clause should have an index if it is a large table.

To get more information what index was used you can use the `explain` statement. Here is what it looks like. Notice the `explain` statement at the very end:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE player (
    ->     id int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
    ->     score MEDIUMINT(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ->     signupdate DATE NOT NULL,
    ->     lastupdate DATE NOT NULL
    -> ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> CREATE TABLE matches (
    ->     matchid int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
    ->     playerid int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
    ->     matchdate DATE NOT NULL
    -> ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT id,score,signupdate FROM player 
    -> JOIN matches ON matches.playerid = player.id 
    -> WHERE lastupdate = now()
    -> ;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> explain
    -> SELECT id,score,signupdate FROM player 
    -> JOIN matches ON matches.playerid = player.id 
    -> WHERE lastupdate = '{today}'
    -> ;
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | player  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 | Using where                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | matches | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE INDEX player_idx_1 
    -> ON player (id)
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE INDEX matches_idx_1 
    -> ON matches (playerid)
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> explain SELECT id,score,signupdate FROM player  JOIN matches ON matches.playerid = player.id  WHERE lastupdate = '{today}';
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref             | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | player  | ALL  | player_idx_1  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL            |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | matches | ref  | matches_idx_1 | matches_idx_1 | 4       | mysql.player.id |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----------------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

add the index for `lastupdate`

```
mysql> CREATE INDEX player_idx_2 
    -> ON player (lastupdate)
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
mysql> explain
    -> SELECT id,score,signupdate FROM player 
    -> JOIN matches ON matches.playerid = player.id 
    -> WHERE lastupdate = curdate()
    -> ;
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref             | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | player  | ref  | player_idx_2  | player_idx_2  | 3       | const           |    1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | matches | ref  | matches_idx_1 | matches_idx_1 | 4       | mysql.player.id |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----------------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: But doesn't mysql use only one index per query? I read that somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it only needs one. It needs the one by `lastupdate` the other one is not used in the query you showed (`SELECT id,score,signupdate FROM player WHERE lastupdate = '{today}'`). In another query by `id` it can use the primary key index. Why otherwise would you be able to define several indicies if there was no opportunity to select the one or the other?

Comment: You do not restrict on `player.id`, you just read the id of players with recent updates. So index `lastupdate` is used. The primary key is important nevertheless, so add that index too.

Comment: With the last update of the OP my statement still does not generally change: index what you use in `WHERE` clause and now also in `JOIN`. Though non of the suggested indicies is sufficient.

Comment: @hol: the other index should be on table `matches` on column `player_id`.

Comment: `player` is the main table where the index on `lastupdate` is used. Then `matches` is joined using the `id`. Not sure in `mysql` but in some other dbms I know the query optimizer does not make a difference what is in the `join` or the `from` clause. That is why I mentioned the `explain` statement. That way the OP can work it out for himself.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely number 2. Primary key is used to uniquely identify a row, and the id attribute is enough for that, so you don't need option 3. And since most of your queries look like what you said, then having an index on lastupdate will definitely be useful to speed your queries.

Comment: But dosent mysql use only one index per query?

Comment: You can have a look at the MySQL manual: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Per table and query only one index, so `lastupdate = today` shrinks to the users of today and then with their id the query goes to table matches.